# Native schema(nxsd): FS and GS delimited file

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, soa, xsd-validation

I need to create native schema NXSD for FS(File Separator) and GS(Group Separator) delimited file. Could anyone help me here please? I am not able to create one. Help will be highly appreciated. Here is the schema below. I need Terminated by values for both FS and GS delimiters... this XSD is working fine if I terminate it by semicolon(;) or comma(,). I will be reading these kind of files using FT adapter in SOA...

```
<?xml version= '1.0' encoding= 'UTF-8' ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/nxsd"
     xmlns:tns="http://www.oracle.com/ApplicationObjectLibrary/GEMS/GEMSMessage/V1" targetNamespace="http://www.oracle.com/ApplicationObjectLibrary/GEMS/GEMSMessage/V1"
     elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" nxsd:version="NXSD" nxsd:stream="chars"
     nxsd:encoding="ASCII">
    <xsd:element name="GEMSMessage">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="GEMS" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nxsd:lookFor="ST">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="ST" type="xsd:string" 
                                 minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" default="ST" nxsd:style="terminated"
                                         nxsd:terminatedBy=";"> --What will be nxsd:terminatedBy value for FS
                            </xsd:element>
                            <xsd:element name="STValue" type="xsd:string"
                                 minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nxsd:style="terminated"
                                         nxsd:terminatedBy=";"/> -- --What will be nxsd:terminatedBy value for GS
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by FS and GS you mean characters x1C and x1D (^\ and ^]), you will have a hard time dealing with them in any XML technology:  they are not allowed to appear as literal characters in any XML documents (although in XML 1.1 they may be referred to using numeric character references).

You will probably do best to write a simple shim to translate the input data into some more XML-compatible form, before trying to validate it with XSD (or whatever schema language you mean by your reference to 'NXSD') or process it with XML-based tools.